# How can I combine 2 or more jquery functions with elements that do the same thing but with different names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make one function that recognizes which instance of `playimg` is being clicked and which popup to fade in. I have like 5 of these and want to compact the code as much as possible.
How can I rewrite this into just one function?

```
$('#playimg2').click(function() {
    $('#popup2').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});

$('#playimg3').click(function() {
    $('#popup3').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});

$('#playimg4').click(function() {
    $('#popup4').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id*="playimg"]').on('click',function(){
        var thisNum = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/);
         $('#popup'+thisNum).fadeIn('fast', function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qn6fwxL9/)

Answer (score 0):

Below, I demonstrate how you can trigger the click event on all of your target elements.

You also need some way to get the number from the string `id`'s (i.e. `playimg2`, `playimg15`, `playimg232`). You can use a regex with capturing groups via something like `/([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/`. This regex should work based off the format of your `id` strings.

**Try this:**

```
var splitRegex = /([a-z]+)([0-9]+)/;

$('#playimg2, #playimg3, #playimg4').click(function () {
    $('#popup' + this.id.match(splitRegex).pop()).fadeIn('fast', function () {
       // Animation complete. 
    });
});
```

You may also consider creating a common class for your `id`'s instead.

```
$('.some-class').click(function () {
    $('#popup' + this.id.match(splitRegex).pop()).fadeIn('fast', function () {
       // Animation complete. 
    });
});
```

Comment: what happens at #10? OP may only be showing a pattern and might have 50 of them. `slice` will fail at 10

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that all your playimg id's look the same. You can access all of them in the following example. Then all you need to do is retreive the last character of the id (the number) and add the animation to the corresponding element.

```
$('id^=playimg').click(function(){
  var _id = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#popup' + _id.subString(_id.length-1)).fadeIn('fast', function(){
    //do stuff
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are those popups descendant (children) HTML elements of #playimg? If yes, you can name it with classes instead of ids like this:

```
<div class="playimg">
    <div class="popup"></div>
</div>
```

and now javascript:

```
$( '.playimg').click(function() {
    $(this).find('popup').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        // Animation complete
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by simply using classes and getting the index of the clicked element and using that to affect it's partner element like this:

```js
$('.playimg').click(function() {
    var cur = $('.playimg').index($(this));
    $('.popup').fadeOut('fast');
    $('.popup').eq(cur).fadeIn('fast', function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

```css
.playimg{
  width: 100px;
  height:20px;
  
  }
.popup{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  display:none;
  background-color:#ccc;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="playimg"> playimg 1</div><br>
<div class="popup">popup 1</div><br>
<div class="playimg"> playimg 2</div><br>
<div class="popup">popup 2</div><br>
<div class="playimg"> playimg 3</div><br>
<div class="popup">popup3</div><br>
```